# Elegant Way To Split First and Last Name From a String With Multiple Punctuations

Tags: python

I have a script where I need to extract the First and Last Name from a string and flip the two. The string looks like this:

> Name: Lastname, Firstname

I came across this solution for my problem:

```
if "name: " in line:
    for nameValue, fname in [q.split(",") for q in line.split(";")]:
       for name, lname in [q.split(":") for q in cnvalue.split(";")]:
           nameFinal=fname.strip() + " " + lname.strip()
```

I was wondering if there would be a more elegant way of actually writing this simple line of code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit messy, but it works:

```
s = 'Name: John, Doe'
print ' '.join(s[6:].replace(" ", "").split(',')[::-1])
>> Doe John
```

Comment: I'd avoid to use `str` as a variable name, as it masks the original python builtin type.

Comment: Also, don’t use magic numbers like in `s[6:]`. Use e.g. `prefix = "Name:"; s[len(prefix):]`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
if line.startswith('Name: '):
    lastname, firstname = line.lstrip('Name: ').split(', ')
```

Comment: If you intend to directly print it: `print '{1} {0}'.format(*s.lstrip('Name: ').split(', '))`

Comment: Use `.split(', ', 1)` to ensure it splits on the first comma only if there’re more of them.

Comment: You have a point, but I wouldn't expect more than one comma in a "last name, name" convention...

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure your lines are always this format, you can also try with a regular expression, something like:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Name: Lastname, Firstname"
>>> p = re.compile(r"Name: (\w+), (\w+)$")
>>> p.sub(r'\2 \1', s)
'Firstname Lastname'
>>>
```

or in fewer lines:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Name: Lastname, Firstname"
>>> re.sub(r"Name: (\w+), (\w+)$", r'\2 \1', s)
'Firstname Lastname'
>>>
```

It is actually easy to test whether the line does match (or not) and also to create the desired output format at will.

Comment: Don’t you have to use some flag so that `\w` will match letters with accents?

Comment: Yes, if you need other characters, you may have to set the locale and use [re.LOCALE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.L). Note that this looks ok for python2.7 but there's a change in 3.6.